# Как убрать лишнюю генерируемую кнопку в создаваемом объекте?

Tags: angularjs

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при создании нового объекта появляются две кнопки Delete? Как убрать лишнюю кнопку?

```
    <main class="movie-info" ng-controller="addMovie">

        <form action="#" class="movie-info__description-container" ng-submit="addNew()">
                <p class="movie-info__info-name">title</p>
                <input type="text" class="movie-info__enter-field" ng-model="title">
                <p class="movie-info__info-name">year</p>
                <input type="text" class="movie-info__enter-field" ng-model="year">

                <button class="movie-info__navigation-button" ng-click="addNew()">Add</button>             
        </form>

        <section class="movie-info__box" ng-repeat="filmInfo in templ track by $index">
            <table class="table">

                <tr >
                    <td>{{filmInfo.title}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{filmInfo.year}}
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <button ng-click="deleteMovie(filmInfo)">Delete</button>
        </section>
    </main>
```

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.Z/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.10/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var handleMovieList = angular.module("handleMovieList",["ngStorage"]);

handleMovieList.controller("addMovie", function ($scope, $localStorage) {

    $localStorage.$default ( {
        templ: []
    });

   $scope.templ = $localStorage.templ;

   $scope.addNew = function () {

           $scope.templ.push ({
               "title":$scope.title,
               "year":$scope.year
           });
           $scope.title = "";
           $scope.year = "";
   };

   $scope.deleteMovie = function (item) {
        var data = $scope.templ.indexOf(item);
        $scope.templ.splice(data, 1);
        console.log(deleteMovie());
   }

});
    </script>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` нужно переместить на уровень выше, т.е. в section

Comment: @vp_arth Ваш совет помог мне, спасибо, но возникла другая проблема: при создании нового объекта теперь появляются две кнопки Delete. Можете подсказать, как сделать, чтобы появлялась только одна кнопка?